# Change onload value within iframe using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, onload

I have a page named somepage.html and the page otherpage.html as iframe in somepage.html
the source of somepage.html is

```
<body><iframe src="otherpage.html name="frame"></body>
```

The source of otherpage.html is

```
<body onload="somefunction()" onunload="otherfunction" >the other content here</body>
```

I want to disable the onload function without touching the code of otherpage.html(iframe). I want to disable it on somepage.html
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

In IE you can use the security="restricted" [attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534622%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  It doesn't do what you want (disable javascript altogether) but should force the IFRAME to run in a differnent zone and prevent it from accessing your page.

The HTML 5 sandbox [attribute](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-iframe-element.html#attr-iframe-sandbox), when implemented, may also be close to what you are looking for.  In particular [allow-scripts](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-iframe-element.html#attr-iframe-sandbox-allow-scripts).  Now you just need it to be implemented in a majority of user's browsers ;)

Comment: Don't think its gonna happen.  I thought it was a nicer answer than this comment though lol.